# Setting cookies for a collapsable jQuery menu when using .toggle()

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle

I'm trying to set up cookies on a collapsable vertical list, I'm using .toggle() to hide and show the list and [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt). I have really simple nav like this:

```
<ul class="menu-sidebar">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 3.1</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

With following CSS:

```
.js .menu-sidebar li ul{display:none;}
```

Then I toggle the list like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu-sidebar li:has(ul) a').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

It's simple and works great but I can't really wrap my head around how to se cookies on that. I've been trying to do it like this:

```
$('.menu-sidebar li:has(ul) a').click(function(){
  $(this).next().toggle();

  if ($(this).next().is(':visible')){
    $.cookie('verticalNav', 'expanded');
  }

  if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')){
    $.cookie('verticalNav', 'collapsed');
  }

  var verticalNav = $.cookie('verticalNav');
  if (verticalNav == 'expanded'){
    $(this).next().show();
  }
});
```

With no luck. Any tips? Thanks! :)

Comment: Amazing script! How can I use it with sub sub itens? Example: 1<br>
1.1<br>
1.1.1<br>
1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take that last block out of the click() method. It's redundant inside of it. (And, of course, wrap it all inside a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` block.)

**UPDATE:** This code will work with multiple submenus by assigning a different cookie value to each one. http://jsfiddle.net/GDudf/13/

```
$('.menu-sidebar li:has(ul) a').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
    if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $.cookie($(this).text(), 'expanded');
    }

    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $.cookie($(this).text(), 'collapsed');
    }
});

$('.menu-sidebar > li').each(function() {
    var verticalNav = $.cookie( $(this).children('a').text() );
    if (verticalNav == 'expanded') {
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: But I'm using `this` in it. It can't be outside the function, or can it... I made a jsfiddle of this http://jsfiddle.net/GDudf/8/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it does not seem to work. Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GDudf/9/

Comment: @any_h: that's not the HTML you posted in the original question.  Using one cookie to store states for multiple submenus is a completely different problem.

Comment: @any_h: updated with your new details. Next time, please be more thorough in your original question.

Comment: So sorry about that. I'll try to be more specific in the future.